# Mysql Document Store find from multiple ids

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to get the values from multiple ids.
The given syntax for single id work:

```
select * from hcig where json_contains(doc, '{\"belongsTo\" : { \"id\": \"9f855e78-f823-4906-9b44-e918ffdb55dc\"} , \"locatedAt\" : {\"id\": \"7970efe1-17cf-4c2d-8ced-42201a2c0f6\"}}')  limit 0,10
```

But what if i want to fetch by multiple ids ?

```
select * from hcig where json_contains(doc, '{\"belongsTo\" : { \"id\": \"9f855e78-f823-4906-9b44-e918ffdb55dc\"} , \"locatedAt\" : {\"id\": [\"7970efe1-17cf-4c2d-8ced-42201a2c0f65,becabb82-06f8-4737-9528-dd97d726df42\"]}}')  limit 0,10
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: I'm old fashioned, so I'd probably solve by storing the data in a normal(ised) form

Comment: @Strawberry :- ok. but i have to find locatedAt.id from multiple json data

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried something like this?

`select doc->>"$.*.id" from hcig;
'